# How to get a pivotal view of Feature and stories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

All,

I'm looking for a view in Azure Boards for a feature (including stories). The current feature timeline does not give stories to view as pivot

Ex. Let us assume current PI is PI 1 with 3 sprints

[Expected View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlLqi.png)

```html
<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=256 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:192pt'>
 <col width=64 span=4 style='width:48pt'>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl6522344 width=64 style='height:14.4pt;width:48pt'>Feature</td>
  <td class=xl6522344 width=64 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>Sprint 1</td>
  <td class=xl6522344 width=64 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>Sprint 2</td>
  <td class=xl6522344 width=64 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>Sprint 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=58 style='height:43.2pt'>
  <td height=58 class=xl6322344 style='height:43.2pt;border-top:none'>Feature 1</td>
  <td class=xl6422344 width=64 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
  width:48pt'>Story 1<br>
    Story 2<br>
    Story 3</td>
  <td class=xl6422344 width=64 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
  width:48pt'>Story 4<br>
    Story 5</td>
  <td class=xl6322344 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Story 6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=38 style='height:28.8pt'>
  <td height=38 class=xl6322344 style='height:28.8pt;border-top:none'>Feature 2</td>
  <td class=xl6422344 width=64 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
  width:48pt'>Story 1<br>
    Story 2</td>
  <td class=xl6322344 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Story 3</td>
  <td class=xl6422344 width=64 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
  width:48pt'>Story 4<br>
    Story 5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=38 style='height:28.8pt'>
  <td height=38 class=xl6322344 style='height:28.8pt;border-top:none'>Feature 3</td>
  <td class=xl6422344 width=64 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
  width:48pt'>Story 1<br>
    Story 2</td>
  <td class=xl6422344 width=64 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
  width:48pt'>Story 3<br>
    Story 4</td>
  <td class=xl6422344 width=64 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
  width:48pt'>Story 5<br>
    Story 6</td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>
```

Comment: When you mentioned feature timeline, you mean [delivery plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops)?

Answer (score 0):

> How to get a pivotal view of Feature and stories

The [Delivery Plans](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans) should be what you are looking for.

> Use the visualization options provided by **Delivery Plans to review the
>   schedule of stories or features** your teams plan to deliver. Delivery
>   Plans show the s**cheduled work items by sprint** (iteration path) of
>   selected teams against a calendar view.

[image]

You could check the [Review team Delivery Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But it doesn't show a pivot of features to stories. It shows either features or stories. Also, When iteration path is 2020-03 for features, and 2020-03.1, 2020-03.2,2020-03.3 etc it is not showing features

Comment: @KarthikRamachandran, Got it. If what you want is such personalized Azure Boards, I worry that there is no such Azure Boards that can fully meet your needs. You may need to submit a user voice to our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.